# Abstract data types naming convention: (Dynamic) Array, Vector, Sequence, List, Container, Buffer

Tags: java, c++, collections, abstract-data-type

Let's consider the (arguably) most famous of all data structures which

- provides an `add` or `append` allowing to add data in (amortized) constant time (at one end of the collection), and
- provides O(1) indexing

Obviously we are all familiar with this concept: In Java we would call it an `ArrayList`, in C++ probably a `vector`, in Python it is "a list", in Scala an `ArrayBuffer` etc.

My question is: What is the most appropriate term to refer to the abstract data type behind these implementations, i.e., which term would (or should?) be associated with the mentioned complexities by all programmers irrespective of their individual background/language?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array

Comment: @SLaks: Oh stupid me; why didn't I come across this during my Wikipedia research... This pretty much settles the issue for me, and if you're willing to post it as an answer, I'll accept it. After thinking about the term a bit more, it also makes perfect sense: The term *Array* is very likely to trigger an association with *O(1) indexing* and prefixing with *Dynamic* adds the association *can grow in O(1)*. Much more clear (at least to me) compared to a somewhat vague "Vector" or "Sequence".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called a [Dynamic Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be the term `List`. While the term is more general than what you seem to be looking for I don't know of another word with a similiar meaning in this context.

The literature calls it like that, too.

Also wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_%28abstract_data_type%29 (they don't say a List needs an access / insertion / delete time of O(1) though)

Comment: Like you said, a list is a little different, I would argue an `ArrayList` is a implementation of the abstract data type List, but there is not ADT that specifies the indexing must be constant time (that I know of).